# Wallet / In-app credits library or service

Tags: web-apps, php, ecommerce

For an ABC app, I have to create a credits system / app-wallet (like ABC app money/credits). This wallet will only be used within the app (**not** like PayTM or MobiKwik).

And users can add credits to this wallet. Also, it'll be used for giving cashback which the user can again use on the same website itself.

Are there any services or reference libraries for the same in php or so?

Answer (score 0):

After some looking around, I found that Citruspay (in India) provides such a service called as Citrus Wallet Solution http://developers.citruspay.com/api/UserManagement/signUp.html

This is not like other wallet integration such as PayTM or MobiKwik. This wallet will be limited to your particular app only. Faasos is one of the apps that uses this wallet. I think other payment gateways should also provide such solutions.